# Where is Firebase FCM token stored on android phone by default

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to know where the firebase fcm instance id token is stored on an android phone. I Already know how to generate a firebase token by using `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` .

I want to know how and where does android stores this token on the device as every time i run this method, the token is same (Except when token is regenerated) . I have a rooted phone so i checked all the databases and preferences files of my app, but the token is not stored in any of those. Since the token is same every time, it must be stored in the phone somewhere. Does anyone knows where the token is stored

Thanks for reading, in advance .

**EDIT**

So I Tried killing and restarting the app and disconnected the internet. Now when i try to get the token, it is still there, so does it mean that it is still on the device?. still don't know the answer

Comment: You say _it is indeed null when we are not connected to internet_.  Not on my phone.  When I turn on airplane mode, kill and restart the app, I get the same non-null token as before.  The token is stored on the device.

Comment: See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

Token is not saved in our mobile . It is stored in Google fcm database. Whenever we use    `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`   It is downloaded from the Google FCM database

Comment: what is your reference?

Comment: Can you please tell the source of your information .

Comment: Try to get fcm token when you are not connected to internet. You will get  null value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517860/how-to-handle-firebaseinstanceid-getinstance-gettoken-null

Comment: Please check out @qbix comment. Once the token is there, then even if disconnected from internet, we can still get it